# How to set this input value when 0 is falsey ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

ReactJS does not like null for a value in `<input>`.

> Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using an
>   empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled
>   components.

Great. My database often returns null because nothing has been set yet.

I am dynamically rendering input fields in a ReactJS app.

```
value={this.state[row_array[0]] || ''}
```

The value for `this.state[row_array[0]]` will sometimes be 0. I want to put 0 in the text field but this evaluates to false ... thus... the empty string `''` is put in the text field.

The problem is `this.state[row_array[0]]` could be anything... 0 is the big problem.

This has some info but nothing helpful for me https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11417

Any ideas about how I can set that `value=0`?

Comment: Why not just do `value={this.state[row_array[0]] || '0'}` ?

Comment: If its null I do not want to insert a '0'

Comment: is `this.state[row_array[0]]` a number or string?

Comment: It can be either. It can also be null

Comment: If you are supporting ES2020 you'll be able to do `value={this.state[row_array[0]] ?? ''}` which will default to `''` only if your state value is `undefined` or `null`

Comment: typo above? @NickParsons

Comment: Support for the experimental syntax 'nullishCoalescingOperator' isn't currently enabled

Comment: @slindsey3000 `??` (the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)) is a new operator which will soon be available in JS (some browsers already support it), but if you're using a transpiler and already support this feature you'd be able to use it

Comment: @slindsey3000 what if you try checking for undefined or null: `this.state[row_array[0]] === null || this.state[row_array[0]] === undefined ? '' : this.state[row_array[0]]`

Comment: Add @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator (https://git.io/vb4Se) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.

Comment: I am not sure how to add that pluggin I'm a rails guy hacking together an Admin React type interface to my DB

Comment: @slindsey3000 if you don't already have it enabled I wouldn't worry about it, as you should be able to write the code that `??` performs using current features - so probably not worth installing a plugin just for it. I believe doing `this.state[row_array[0]] === null || this.state[row_array[0]] === undefined ? '' : this.state[row_array[0]]` would be somewhat equivelent to what `??` does.

Comment: Oh snap @NickParsons that worked. Been f'n with this for 2 hours! Bless you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the conditional operator instead, and check for null:

```
value={this.state[row_array[0]] === null ? '' : this.state[row_array[0]]}
```

Setting the value of an input this way tells React that you want to control the component. If it's uncontrolled initially, this will result in a warning - to avoid that warning, make sure to specify that the input is [controlled from the start](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

Live demo:

```js
const row_array = [0];
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 0: null };
    this.updateData = this.updateData.bind(this);
  }

  updateData (event) {
    console.log('updated');
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input id={row_array[0]} className="data-input" name={row_array[0]} placeholder="" value={this.state[row_array[0]] === null ? '' : this.state[row_array[0]]} onChange={this.updateData} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <NameForm />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

If it may also be `undefined`, and not just `null`, then check that as well:

```
value={this.state[row_array[0]] === null || this.state[row_array[0]] === undefined ? '' : this.state[row_array[0]]}
```

Comment: Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type undefined to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

Comment: I tried exactly this first. But that leads to the error above

Comment: To avoid that warning, you should [make the input controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) - make sure React always handles changes, so they go into state. Eg `value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}` and `handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }`

Comment: id={row_array[0]}
                                                      className="data-input"
                                                      name={row_array[0]}
                                                      placeholder=""
                                                      value={this.state[row_array[0]] === null ? '' : this.state[row_array[0]]} 
                                                      onChange={this.updateData}

Comment: I believe I do that. I have onChange=

Comment: updateData = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

Comment: I made a live snippet, it appears to work fine with no warnings

Comment: I def was getting warnings. @nick got it above and it seems fine. thx for help though. Bless you

Comment: I thought you said it could only be a number, string, or `null`. If it might be `undefined` too, then you'll have to check for that as well

Comment: I really have no idea why what you have for your answer gives me the warning I posted above VS what @NickParsons suggested... but his does not have the warning. I just tripled verified it. They seem very much the same... very strange

Answer (score 0):

When asked for a variable, either with an if or with a ternary operator, it is evaluated to be non-null and non-undefined.

You can try.

```js
class X extends React.Component {
    state = {};
    render (){
      const xdata = this.state[row_array[0]];
      const value = xdata ? xdata : '';
      return (
        <input type="text" value={value} />
      )
    }
}
```